# Can a button cell battery power car cigarette lighter (in the shape of a ring)?

Tags: internal-consistency, hard-science, materials, electricity, thermodynamics

Is it possible to make a fake golden ring which can light a candle on the push of a button and power it with button cell battery (either coin cell or watch button size)?

I have a fraud guy trying to replicate a miracle. When he is inside his temple, he uses lasers and high tech gadgetry (see [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/225250/how-to-miraculously-light-any-candle-by-chemical-or-technological-means) for details). This ring would be a backup for that miracle. I need to know if it would be possible.

Comment: Hard science tag should never be the only tag on a question because this tag frames how a question should be answered, not the topic.

Comment: @L.Dutch ok, added reality check too.

Comment: Please read the tag description: also the reality check tag cannot be used alone. They both frame how the question shall be answered, not the question content

Comment: @L.Dutch added electricity tag too.

Comment: ??? (1) You can very obviously use the battery to charge a capacitor to get whatever peak current you want. (Like a flash lamp.) (2) It is trivially easy to find out the characteristics of various common button cells. For example, the archetypal [CR2032](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Button_cell) twenty-millimeter non-rechargeable lithium button cell has a capacity of 220 mA·h; its nominal voltage is 3 V; the maximum current draw is about 100 mA (this will shorten its life considerably, but they are cheap). So you have about 0.3 W available to power your lighter, even without a capacitor.

Comment: P.S.  Car cigarette lighters (technically known as [automobile auxiliary power outlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_auxiliary_power_outlet)) are high power sources, on the order of 100 to 200 W (1 to 3 horse-power, for the hippophiles). They are very rarely used to light cigarettes; the most common use is to power chargers for mobile phones and such like.

Comment: @AlexP sounds like an answer rather than two comments.  Question is clearly defined and not everyone has a physics/electronics background.

Comment: @AlexP I am asking about the lighter part/plug, not the charging part.  In car lighters it is Nichrome heating element (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome), I am asking whether you can put it into ring. Or otherwise make a simple ring that can light a candle. There is also this thing: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1548/6499/files/lightermount_3_large_07bf6bf8-67e7-44d0-942e-62e605bbc568_1024x1024.gif?v=1563982196 I don't know physics that well, I am just a writer...

Comment: Car cigarette lighter on cell batteries ? Don't see how the question relates to WB.. temple ? miracle ?

Comment: *"Nichrome heating element":* Resistive heating is a non-starter; the power is waaaay too low. What you need is a spark or maybe a powerful flash of light. I don't know how to arrange that, that is why I commented instead of answering. But if you strip the fantastic story and simply ask how to light a candle with the power provided by a button cell, you can profitably ask this question on [Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AlexP That one is simple enough.  do this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybfan6PteQI . How to do it repeatedly, that's the issue here...

Comment: @jo1storm If you're looking to engineer a device we're not the place to discuss that. Judging by the video you believe this to be possible and are asking for a schematic or design discussion.

Comment: @sphennings no. Judging by that video, the foil burns up and you don't have a device any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

[image]

You can buy the pictured butane lighter ring [here](https://sensaccessories.com/products/lighter-ring?variant=41710716190874&currency=USD&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjwlcaRBhBYEiwAK341jdYM81800eXpx0Qlpyz8a41rc71a_dTcjKsr5DXj3_iceEImZ38t7hoCpTAQAvD_BwE)

Battery powered lighters also exist which create electrical arcs instead of using combustible fuel.

[image]

Combining these two technologies seems like a trivial engineering matter with modern technology.

Comment: But, is the arc lighter powered by a button cell battery or something stronger?

Comment: That one I think is a lithium battery you charge by a USB port. I think a 2023 cell or something common like that is probably too weak, but maybe a battery of that size using lithium or advanced material science could do it.

Comment: Also worth noting is that battery voltage is  dependent on the material used, and the size determines the capacity for it to discharge that voltage for a long time. Ex: All alkaline cells have 1.5V, but a D cell will last a lot longer than a AAA. Lithium cells are 3.7V. A high voltage is required to create an arc, but if you just need to fake 1 miracle, you don't need high capacity, so you can use smaller cells.

Comment: Lets just say that I need to fake a miracle for half an hour. Light every candle brought to you.